# Blender 3: booleans have some hidden state that makes them unworkable

Tags: modifiers

In Blender 3.0.0, the booleans became faster but unfortunately, they seems to have some internal state (cache?) which makes exactly the same model behave differently (as in, booleans work or not) depending on which object has been last modified.

[image]

In the attached model, there is `Cyl1` in which `Cyl2` makes a hole. The product is `union`ed with `A`. Which does not work if anything is modified in modifiers of `Cyl1` (as simple as toggle modifier's visibility back and forth so nothing should change). But the booleans work again if the same thing is done in `A`. In particular, after opening the model, nothing is visible, but toggling twice the visibility icon in the `Union` modifier in `A` makes `A` visible. I restarted Blender several times, reopened the file and the problem repeats.

And these are only two cylinders. Am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a dependency cycle.  Cyl 1 has a boolean difference with Cyl 2.  Cyl 2 has a boolean difference with Cyl 1.  Which should happen first?  Blender can't know, and it can't evaluate every object in an infinite loop.  Every time you change modifiers (or exit edit mode), Blender re-evaluates the affected object once, then the other object.  But the output depends on the evaluation order.